# gsub or sub out the first '_' but not the following

Tags: gsub

I have mistakenly linked up some columns with `_` but now I need to split them on just the first `_`.

For example the names are `plate_Vancouver` and other names are `plate_1_Vancouver_east`, but I want them to split into just col 1 being plate and col 2 being `Vancouver` or `1_Vancouver_east`

I was going to attempt it by replacing the first _ with `/` then splitting on `/`.

```r
sub("\\_", "_", combined, fixed = TRUE) #remove '_' and convert to '/'
```

but something is wrong with the code I think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string::str_split` to split with an underscore into two substrings:

```r
x <- c("plate_Vancouver", "plate_1_Vancouver_east")
library(stringr)
str_split(x, "_",  n = 2)
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "plate"     "Vancouver"

[[2]]
[1] "plate"            "1_Vancouver_east"
```

Or, you can use two `sub` calls:

```r
sub("_.*", "", x)
## => [1] "plate" "plate"
sub("^[^_]*_", "", x)
## => [1] "Vancouver"        "1_Vancouver_east"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/5D93Tw).

Here, `sub("_.*", "", x)` removes all after first `_`, and `sub("^[^_]*_", "", x)` removes all up to the first one.

Comment: so if my df has multiple columns and I only want to process a certain column with your 2 sub commands how do I make sure only that col is processed? Do I just replace your x with df$code?

Comment: `df$code1 <- sub("_.*", "", df$code)` and `df$code2 <- sub("^[^_]*_", "", df$code)`